# How to create an 'impression' effect in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, 3d, effects, drop-shadow

I am wondering how to create an impression effect in illustrator.  If you take a look at the attached jpg, I am hoping to make this cloud look as if it has been impressed upon the magenta background.  What I am thinking is an inverse drop shadow if it is possible, but any other thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried and tell us why you aren't content with the results? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any reference or concept to see what you after?

Comment: Try searching the terms "emboss" and "deboss." Is that what you're after? Yes? Please edit your question. No? Do you want the shape to appear as if below the level of the background? Please edit your question to more precisely define (show) what you want to achieve. Then, this might be a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably many ways to do this. Anyhoo, here's one fairly simple method that might work for you.

1. Cut out the cloud shape from the red rectangle using the pathfinder Minus Front option
2. Add a drop shadow to the red shape, and also add a white inner glow with very little blur
3. Put a blue rectangle behind it
4. Perhaps finish by adding a texturiser "sandstone" effect to both the red and blue shapes

Example

[image]